# Issue: SPSS computes impossible data with Expectation Maximization for missing values

Tags: spss, missing-data, expectation-maximization

I am a masterstudent in behavioural sciences, currently writing my thesis. Unfortunately statistics isn't my biggest talent, so I was hoping someone out here could help me with an issue I am facing.

I have a dataset in SPSS with missing values for different variables. I ran a Missing Value Analysis using EM but SPSS computed impossible values for the missing data in some cases. For example: -4 on a variable that has a range of answer-options from 1 to 7 or -10 on a variable that is a percentage. How do I make sure SPSS computes values that are fitting to my dataset?

Thank you!

Comment: Look in the Command Syntax Reference guide to learn whether MVA procedure has any option to restrict the range of values to impute.